# java vs php benchmark

Tags: java, php, benchmarking

I'm a php developer, but recently had to write the same application twice, once in php and once in java, for a class I'm taking at school. For curiosity I did a benchmark on the two and found that the java version was 2 to 20 times slower than the php version if the database is accessed, and 1 to 10 times slower without DB access. I see two immediate possibilites:

1. I suck at java.
2. I can finally tell people to quit whining about php.

I posted my servlet code [here](http://pastebin.com/RaMkENuL). I don't want any nit-picky whining or minor improvements, but can someone see a horrible glaring performance issue in there? Or can anybody explain why Java feels like it has to suck?

I've always heard people say that java is faster and more scalable than php, especially my teacher, he is convinced of it, but the more requests that are made, the slower java gets. php doesn't seem to be affected by increased loads but remains constant.

Comment: PHP _is_ very fast, but Java is a byte-code compiled language, so it's inherently faster.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. Everyone on the internet raves that java is sooooo much faster, but on my server it sucketh to a very high degree in comparison to php. Did you read the question?

Comment: A third possibility is that you didn't do the performance measurements properly.

Comment: I request the page several times and see how long it takes. I don't see how much could go wrong with that.

Comment: every one i know says php is faster, it depends who you talk to\ listen to

Comment: @regality - There is a big problem in doing performance measurements like that; read up on "JVM warmup".  Also, your Java creates a new DB connection for each request; read up on "JDBC connection pool".

Comment: @regality - There are other problems with your Java to, but you've said that you don't want "nit-picking" so I won't waste my breath.

Comment: Indeed. A connection pool matters *a lot*. Java is a bit more low-level than PHP. PHP takes lot of nastiness from your hands, a lot is already optimized behind the scenes, but in Java you have more fine grained control over this yourself. As to your code: loading the JDBC driver on *every* connection acquirement is unnecessary. Just do it once during application's startup. Oh, reading/writing by a buffer (BufferedReader/BufferedWriter) would also help a lot.

Comment: When you say Java was 1-10x to 2-20x slower - can you state the values you got including the units for both PHP and Java? I want to know if we're talking about milliseconds or seconds/minutes.

Comment: @Stephen C (or @BalusC), not making a connection on every request made the difference. It put it about equal to php on the requests with db results, if you want to post your response as an answer I can mark it as accepted. @BalusC, I did a quick search and couldn't find any documentation for a bufferedwriter, do you have a source that I could research that from?

Comment: BufferedWriter: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html

Comment: @regality I posted an answer as "community wiki" which encapsulates responses made by @Stephen and @BalusC. I won't get credit for the answer so if you like you can accept and edit it.

Comment: It goes to show that a well written program in your preferred language can be much faster than a not so well written program in a language which others say is faster. There is a similar argument with Java vs C++ performance.

Comment: @typo.pl, I only measure in micro-seconds in my Java applications. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a mature Java web application the Servlet would make use of an existing JDBC connection pool. Establishing a new connection will be by far the greatest cost you pay in time.

Calling `Class.forName` for every attempt to get the connection will also cause an unnecessary slow down.

JVM tuning could also be a factor. In an enterprise environment the JVM memory and possibly GC configurations would be adjusted and tuned to achieve a desirable balance between responsiveness and resource utilization.

As Stephen C points out, the JVM also has a concept of a sort of "warm up".

All that said, I have no idea how PHP compares to Java and I feel both languages offer great solutions to separate non-disjoint sets of needs.

Answer (score 1):

Based on not much info (where the best decisions are made), my guess is the `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` in `getConnection()` is the big timesink.

Creating a `new String` in importFile when the `char[]` can be passed to out.println is me nitpicking.

Comment: Not using a connection pool is a bigger timesink. Loading a driver can be done in a ms or 50. But obtaining a brand new unpooled connection from the DB can take 200~500ms or even longer, depending on network latency and many other factors. Obtaining a pooled connection is basically almost a no-op.

Comment: Calling `Class.forName(...)` multiple times for the same class name is wasteful, but it is not as expensive as you might imagine, and unlikely to be a bottleneck in this case.   One of the first things that the classloader does is to see if it has already loaded the class.  If it has, then it just returns the previously loaded Class.

Answer (score 0):

Your test seems to reflect initial overhead moreso than steady-state performance.  Try doing the non-DB tests multiple times in a loop (so that each test wold run the code multiple times) and look at the linear relationship between runtime and number of iterations.  I suspect the incremental cost for java is lower than that for php